# How to Change location of postgres cluster and database within the same machine?

Tags: postgresql, linux

I have my present database cluster of postgres at /mnt/my_hard_drive which I want to change to /home/myfolder. I also want to move all my databases present in the present cluster to /home/myfolder. Is there a way to do so?

I know one way for doing so is to dump my databases in some form e.g. .sql and reconstruct them from there. But considering my database size if 5TB I dont want to use this approach. Is there some other way to achieve this..since my machine is same...all I want to do is to move my database from hard drive to my home folder. Please suggest

Comment: You can just stop the DB, copy the cluster on FS level and start the DB with new cluster directory.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Thanks a lot for replying. I did stop postgres. But since I am a newbie with postgres I dont know as to how should I copy the database at the FS level. Also how should I start the DB with new cluster directory. For this do I have to create a new cluster. If yes, then how should I create one?

Comment: "copy at fs level" just means `cp -r /old/cluster/path /new/cluster/path`

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Thanks a lot for replying. I have copied my data. Now how should I start postgres with new cluster directory.

Comment: @JannatArora `pg_ctl start -D /new/cluster/path`

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Thanks for replying. When I use pg_ctl it shows pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/home/Database/postmaster.pid" permission denied. Even though I change permission via chmod to 777/700 then also it continues to show the error.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko When I run pg_ctl start -D /new/cluster/path. I gives me the error: server starting postgres@Server:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin$ postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/home/destination_data_directory/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Can you please help me figure out the error..please. Also thanks for replying